# display error or success message when using c# foreach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I am using C#. How can I display a success message if all data were submitted, or an error message and break the loop in case there was an error during the foreach loop?

This is my try, but I don't know the best way to display the messages:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataDTO data = new DataDTO();
    BaseDAO connexion = new BaseDAO();

    foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
    {
        data.lblId = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblId")).Text;


        try
        {
            connexion.update_database(data);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Display error message and break loop
        }
    }

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    LoadGrid();
    // Display success message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataDTO data = new DataDTO();
    BaseDAO connexion = new BaseDAO();
    bool success = true;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
    {
        data.lblId = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblId")).Text;


        try
        {
            connexion.update_database(data);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Display error message and break loop
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('<success message>')", true);
            success = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    LoadGrid();
    // Display success message

    if (success)
    {
       ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('<success message>')", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: asp.net? MessageBox.Show?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention.  Now fixed.  I think this answer *now* matches you requirements, as there is only ever *one* message shown.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to enclose the `foreach` inside the try..catch as like the following:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    DataDTO data = new DataDTO();
    BaseDAO connexion = new BaseDAO();
    try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
        {
            // Perform operations here
        }
       // show success message  
    }
    catch
    {
        // Show Some Error message
        isError=true;
    }
    // Rest of process         
}
```

You need not to use try..catch in each iteration, Instead of doing that you can enclose the foreach inside the try block. So that loop will automatically break and the catch will execute if there is any exception.

Comment: asp.net? MessageBox.Show?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataDTO data = new DataDTO();
    BaseDAO connexion = new BaseDAO();

    try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
        {
            data.lblId = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblId")).Text;
            connexion.update_database(data);
        }

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        LoadGrid();
        // Display success message
        // Success Alert
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Update Successfully')", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Display error message and break loop
        // Error Alert
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", string.Format("alert('Record Update Failed: {0}')", ex.Message), true);
    }
}
```

I suggest you enclose the whole process inside the try-catch statement.

Comment: I still get the success message even when there's an error (I stop the database services before updating in order to check)

Comment: both will alert but with different message.

Answer (score 0):

`return`  keyword is used to terminate out of the loops.

I will take a `boolean` variable to check the status either a `success` or `failure`

```
bool isSuccess = true;    
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
{
    data.lblId = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblId")).Text;               
    try
    {
       connexion.update_database(data);
    }
    catch
    {
       isSuccess = false;
       // Display error message and break loop
       return;
    }
}
if(!isSuccess)
   //Show success message
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
LoadGrid();
```

Comment: I still get the success message even when there's an error (I stop the database services before updating in order to check)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to show error massage from `.NET` You must add some exception, and then raise the error message.

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   

    DataDTO data = new DataDTO();
    BaseDAO connexion = new BaseDAO();
    try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
        {
            data.lblId = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblId")).Text;
            connexion.update_database(data);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message); //message from .NET
        //MessageBox.Show("your custom message"); // custom message.
        isError=true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: asp.net? MessageBox.Show?